# why the type castings (UINT)(void*)(DWORD) are needed?

Tags: c++, c, mfc, casting

This is a default HashKey function in MFC's CMap class.

```
AFX_INLINE UINT AFXAPI HashKey(ARG_KEY key)
{
　　// default identity hash - works for most primitive values
　　return ((UINT)(void*)(DWORD)key) >> 4;
}
```

My question is why the type casting **(DWORD)** and **(void*)** are needed?. I guess the (DWORD) may have some relationship with compatibility affairs for 16-bit machines. But I'm confused about the **void***.

Comment: Nope, no reason. Whoever wrote this code just had no idea what they were doing.

Comment: Dunno, but `(void*)` and one of `(UINT)` and `(DWORD)` are useless.

Comment: @R.. This code snippet is coped from “Programming Windows with MFC"

Comment: Someone was on something, probably.

Comment: @R.. Considering that you do not know the history of that function or the intent of the original programmers, it's a little naive to suggest that whoever wrote it had no idea what they were doing. There *WAS* a point to this madness at the time the code was originally written, which Hans Passant explains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<class ARG_KEY>
AFX_INLINE UINT AFXAPI HashKey(ARG_KEY key)
{
    // default identity hash - works for most primitive values
    return (DWORD)(((DWORD_PTR)key)>>4);
}
```

That's what that function looks like today.  Your version came from a very old version of MFC, old enough to still support 16-bit programs.  MFC was first released in 1992, the days of Windows version 3.  MFC versions 1.0 through 2.5 supported 16-bit targets. The current version of the function is good for 32-bit and 64-bit code.

In 16-bit code, one option to select was the *memory model*.  You could pick cheap 16-bit *near* pointers or expensive 32-bit *far* pointers.  So the extra void* cast trims the value to the memory model size.

Answer (score 2):

The cast to `DWORD` will reduce the size to a `DWORD`.

The cast to `void*` will reduce the size to a pointer.

There is not much more that can be inferred from these casts, and in a realistic environment it's overkill, but it's fair to expect an optimizing compiler not to do any unnecessary work through these conversions.

Comment: But isn't it that  sizeof (DWORD)==sizeof( void*)？So the casting just makes no sense?

Comment: the size of the a pointer differs on machines. On 64bit machine void * is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

The casting to `DWORD`(Double Word) is needed here to tell the CPU which bytes he need to shift in this case he shift only the `DWORD` bits.The `(void*)` casting is to make the number you just shift 4 times to a pointer(casting to generic address size).

**The size of void* can be different between OS(32b system or 64b system) because of that you must do this casting.**

The last casting to `(UINT)` is to cast the pointer to unsigned integer to get the memory address as a number.